# Replace content of NSMutableArray with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm working on an app that needs to retrieve some data from a server. I have created a "Server" class which handles all the communication and has a NSMutableArray *sessionData variable where I would like to store the data coming from the server (btw, is this approach correct?).

I have the data in an NSArray. I would like the NSMutableArray to have the same content of the NSArray but I didn't find any way to do this (sessionData = requestResult).

(subquestion: do I have to initialize in some way the NSMutableArray before using ? I have only declared it with @property and @synthesize)

Comment: I have tried this but didnt work: [sessionData removeAllObjects]; [sessionData setArray:result];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
sessionData = [result mutableCopy];
[result release];
```

Or

```
NSMutableArray *sessionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfArray:result];
```

Answer (score 5):

The code you tried (from the comment) should have worked. The reason it did not work is that your `sessionData` was `nil`.

You need to initialize your `sessionData` - set it to `[NSMutableArray array]` in the initializer; then your code

```
[sessionData removeAllObjects];
[sessionData setArray:result];
```

will work perfectly. You do not even need the first line - the second one *replaces* the content of `sessionData` with that of the `result`.

Comment: Thank you. Is this code good to initialize it (from the the init method of my class) ? self->sessionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: @anthmad Yes, this initialization code should work. If you are not on ARC, consider assigning to a property, rather than to its backing ivar; if you're on ARC, it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you could do this:

```
NSMutableArray *session = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:someArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example something like this:

```
NSArray *requestData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
_sessionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:requestData];
[requestData release];

NSLog(@"%@", [sessionData objectAtIndex:0]); // 2012-03-30 15:53:39.446 <app name>[597:f803] 3
NSLog(@"count: %d", [sessionData count]); //2012-03-30 15:53:39.449 <app name>[597:f803] count: 3
```

Comment: sessionData is a property that I need to access from other methods. Your code will create a local mutable array ?

Answer (score 0):

**1. is this approach correct?**

Yes.

**2. I didn't find any way to do this (sessionData = requestResult)**

As many have suggested you can use `mutableCopy` to assign `requestResult` to `sessionData`
OR you can use `arrayWithArray` as one answer suggests.

**3. do I have to initialize in some way the NSMutableArray before using ?**

Yes. If you are changing any variable it must have memory allocated.